# Find appropriate functions for fitting curves

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I produce, using Mathematica, the red curves of the following schematic?

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot use simple trigonometric functions such as `Sin`, `Cos` etc because these curves are not harmonic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the values of B and D, and A and C the same ?

Comment: @yarchik Yes, they are the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why something like `Sin[phi]`, `Sin[phi + c]` where `c` is a constant near `Pi` doesn't work? what exactly are the requirements of the schematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[-x]} + Cos[x]/2, {x, -Pi - 0.01, 3 Pi + 0.01}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {Sin[#] &},
  MeshStyle -> 
  Directive[PointSize[Medium], RGBColor[
   0.4907806591595267, 0.4396552977670637, 0.6375127068715876]], 
 PlotStyle -> RGBColor[
  0.9849415764566248, 0.46166225896480656`, 0.6024155545011171], 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]